# my wpf menuitem commands don't trigger

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command, menuitem

I'm working with WPF and MVVM.

I created my dynamic `Menu` two different ways, but both don't work.

First:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding MeuPaudi}">
        <Menu.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=MenuSelecionado}" />
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Texto}" />
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding MenuFilhos}"/>
            </Style>
        </Menu.Resources>
    </Menu>
</DockPanel>
```

Second:

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding MeuPaudi}">
    <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Texto}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="{Binding Path=IsCheckable}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=MenuFilhos}"/>
            <Setter Property="Command"  Value="{Binding MenuSelecionado}" />
        </Style>
    </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
</Menu>
```

I also create a `Button` to test if the command works properly:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=MenuSelecionado}"/>
```

And it works. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should ensure that your bindings are working fine. Quick way to check if your bindings are not working, is to add a dummy converter in your binding and put a breakpoint in Convert Method. If breakpoint is not hit means, means your binding is not getting fired i,e either path of property is not correct or data source is not attached.

Also you should remove Style:BasedOn. as this is not required. Following code should work.

```
<MenuItem Header="Main Menu" ItemsSource="{Binding MeuPaudi}">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding Texto}"/>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Command" Value="{Binding MenuSelecionado}"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Can you see the menu items if you remove the menu item style but keep the itemssource binding? you should see atleast items populated.if it works then issue seems to be with style. Otherwise you need to check the individual items bindings. Also you can check if any binding errors are fired in output window in debug mode.

Comment: Here is a link to smiliar workign sample [link](http://blog.typps.com/2011/05/binding-data-from-viewmodel-to-wpf-menu.html)